# Python program showing exception

Tags: python, step

I want to run this below program using python..

```
            from __future__ import print_function

            import sys

            from OCC.STEPControl import STEPControl_Reader
            from OCC.IFSelect import IFSelect_RetDone, IFSelect_ItemsByEntity
            from OCC.Display.SimpleGui import init_display
            from OCC.Display.WebGl import threejs_renderer
            from OCC.STEPCAFControl import STEPCAFControl_Reader

            step_reader = STEPControl_Reader()
            status = step_reader.ReadFile('./models/part_ARROWS_ASM.stp')

            if status == IFSelect_RetDone:  # check status
                failsonly = False
                step_reader.PrintCheckLoad(failsonly, IFSelect_ItemsByEntity)
                step_reader.PrintCheckTransfer(failsonly, IFSelect_ItemsByEntity)

                ok = step_reader.TransferRoot(1)
                _nbs = step_reader.NbShapes()
                aResShape = step_reader.Shape(1)
            else:
                print("Error: can't read file.")
                sys.exit(0)
            #display, start_display, add_menu, add_function_to_menu = init_display()
            #display.DisplayShape(aResShape, update=True)
            #start_display()

            my_renderer = threejs_renderer.ThreejsRenderer(background_color="#123345")
            my_renderer.DisplayShape(aResShape)
```

Its running successfully without this module OCC.STEPCAFControl. After running above program found this below eeror.

```
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "D:\software\python\pythonocc-core-master\examples\core_load_step_ap203.py", line 26, in <module>
                from OCC.STEPCAFControl import STEPCAFControl_Reader
            ImportError: No module named 'OCC.STEPCAFControl'
```

After got this error paste OCC.STEPCAFControl this module within OCC folder and this problem is solved but its showing another exception which is mentioned below.

```
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "D:\software\python\pythonocc-core-master\examples\core_load_step_ap203.py", line 26, in <module>
                from OCC.STEPCAFControl import STEPCAFControl_Reader
              File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\OCC\STEPCAFControl.py", line 28, in <module>
                _STEPCAFControl = swig_import_helper()
              File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\OCC\STEPCAFControl.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
                _mod = imp.load_module('_STEPCAFControl', fp, pathname, description)
              File "C:\Python34\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
                return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
            ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

How to solve this issue? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

For scientific python on windows, your best bet is to install WinPython, Python(x,y), Enthought Python or Anaconda rather than trying to install everything manually. Any of these will install most packages you are likely to need, and should configure them correctly.

Comment: Installed WinPython but still showing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The python module is probably trying to load a DLL called _STEPCAFControl.pyd
(I'm guessing at the extension).  If you have a STEPCAFControl.dll with this name, you can rename it _STEPCAFControl.pyd, and it may work.  If the names is not correct, you need to look into the STEPCAFControl.py file, and find the .DLL file name.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. I have this file _STEPCAFControl.pyd within OCC folder. I checked this STEPCAFControl.py file but it dose not contain any file name with extension .DLL.

Comment: That's the file you need but it needs to be in the right place for the DLL loader to find it.  Rather than troubleshoot this and bump into the next problem immediately, a better approach would be to properly install the components you need.

Comment: @tripleee basically I have installed PythonOCC0.16.exe file which contains the OCC file. Its installed the OCC module but some module is missing like STEPCAFControl.py is missing. So I am not getting any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Its also possible that this .pyd file (actually a dll) was compiled with a different version of python and does not link when you try and load it.   You need to check with whoever provided this file to see which python is required.